# Show link which is inside a hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's say I have this inner link which is positioned inside a hidden div (`display:none`) - the div toggles when a button is clicked:

```
<a name="here">Show me!</a>
```

How can I make the element **visible** when somebody enters the url: mypageurl#**here**, without clicking the toggle button (make it visible by default when this specific link is entered)?

Comment: You could check the url of the page on document.ready and write code to show the div if the url contains your intended #ref

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$().ready(function () {
    var hash = $.trim(window.location.hash);
    if (hash != '') {
        var prt = $('[name="' + hash.substr(1) + '"]').parent();
        prt.show();
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="display:none;"><a name="here">Show me!</a></div>
```

Full code!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the CSS "visibility:hidden", then use JavaScript to change that to "visibility:visible" when someone enters a certain phrase.

Alternatively, you could just use display: ""; or display:block on the "display:none" div when the same action occurs, again using some JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below script.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var loc = document.location.hash;
    if(loc == "#test")
    {
        $('#test').show();
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the source code of a simple page that I made:

```
<html>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js "></script>
<body>
<div id="hide" style="display:none">
    <a name="here">Show me!</a>
</div>
</body>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if(document.location.href.search("#hide")>0){
            $("#hide").toggle();
        }
    });
</script>
</html>
```

It will show the *div* with the *id* `hide` if the page has the text `"#hide"`, else it remains hidden.